# Can I use switch - case, in actionPerformed method in Java

Tags: java, events, action

I would like to check on which actionEvent has occurred with `ActionEvent e` and `e.getSource()`. Can I use a switch case for this?

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    switch(e.getSource()){
        case radius:
            double r = validate(radius.getText());
            break;
        case height:
            double h = validate(height.getText());
            break;
        case out:
            out.setText(String.valueOf(h*r));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can use switch in `actionPerformed`.

No, you can't use it like you showed it here.

`switch` only supports primitive types and `enum`s (and `String`, but only in Java 7 and later).

Another problem is that the case-values values must be compile time constants.

You'll need code like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == radius) {
        double r = validate(radius.getText());
    else if (e.getSource() == height) {
        double h = validate(height.getText());
    else if (e.getSource() == out) {
        out.setText(String.valueOf(h*r));
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also switch on Enums.

Comment: Thanks, to bad. So I guess I can't use switch, case then.

Comment: Are Strings really allowed in switch? I though it's comming only in Java 7, no?

Comment: Josh Bloch made a push for it but I havent heard anything

Comment: Java 7 will allow Strings for switch, as part of Project Coin. It is not allowed in previous versions.

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, I got mixed up in my explanation of what compile time constants can be. Strings are of course not valid in a switch, I tried to clarify that in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

No, you can't. The types you can use in a switch statement is very limited.
See [The switch Statement](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

You can of course just write this as a series of "if" and "else if" statements.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's good to know, I wanted to ask to be sure there wasn't some way around it before abandon it for, 'if, else'.

Answer (score 4):

As other solutions have pointed out, you cannot use switch in this context.  However, rather than implementing one `ActionListener` containing a big if-then block, why not implement separate `ActionListeners` for each event source?  This is a much more OO-based approach.

Typically your `ActionListener` implementations would be (small) anonymous inner classes anyway, and hence you wouldn't have to deal with a huge proliferation of .java files.

Answer (score 1):

The `ActionEvent` contains an `ActionCommand` field which is a String. If not set while creating the `Button` it defaults to the text of the button. You can use that instead.

Something like:

```java
switch(e.getActionCommand()) {
    case "Radius":
          ....
    case "Height":
          ....
}
```