# Switch Case In ActionPerformed?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, cardlayout, abstract-action

Ive gone through some stack overflow questions and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667060/can-i-use-switch-case-in-actionperformed-method-in-java#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20you%20can%20use%20switch%20in%20actionPerformed%20.) similar question.

From what I understand using a switch statement in an actionPerformed method for this context will not work and an if-else statement is required.

Is there a more efficient way to do this without having repetitive code? I've heard I could use Abstract Action to give multiple buttons the same action but i haven't figured out how to use it properly.

```java
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == loginButton){
            cardLayout.show(cards, LOGIN_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == signUpButton){
            cardLayout.show(cards, SIGN_UP_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == transactionHistoryButton){
            cardLayout.show(cards,TABLE_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == depositButton){
            cardLayout.show(cards, DEPOSIT_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == withdrawButton){
            cardLayout.show(cards, WITHDRAW_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == checkBalanceButton){
            cardLayout.show(cards,BALANCE_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == logout){
            cardLayout.show(cards, OPTION_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == backButtonP1){
            cardLayout.show(cards, OPTION_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == backButtonP2){
            cardLayout.show(cards, OPTION_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == backButtonP3){
            cardLayout.show(cards, UNLOCKED_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == backButtonP4){
            cardLayout.show(cards, UNLOCKED_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == backButtonP5){
            cardLayout.show(cards, UNLOCKED_PANEL);
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == backButtonP6){
            cardLayout.show(cards, UNLOCKED_PANEL);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This: *"From what I understand I cant use a switch statement in an actionPerformed method"* is inherently false. Where do you get this from? Please clarify your question with more details.  You may have heard that you *shouldn't* do this, that "switchboard listeners" should be avoided, but that is a matter of design opinion and not a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: If you look at the question i am referring to, multiple answers said that a switch statement is possible, but not in this use and that an if-else statement would need to be used, I will update the question to be more specific

Comment: Again, your opening premise, that you ***can't*** use a switch in an ActionListener, is a false statement. You may wish to fix this part of your question.

Comment: For example, if you simply get the ActionEvent's actionCommand String, via `e.getActionCommand()`, you can easily do a switch statement with that.

Comment: Please look at [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3827424/522444) that talks about restrictions on switch statement usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java switch statement: Constant expression required, but it IS constant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3827393/java-switch-statement-constant-expression-required-but-it-is-constant)

Comment: As for how to use AbstractAction please look at questions answered by [MadProgrammer](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+abstractaction+madprogrammer+site%3Astackoverflow.com), [camickr](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+abstractaction+camickr+site%3Astackoverflow.com) and [myself](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+abstractaction+hovercraft+site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> From what I understand using a switch statement in an actionPerformed method for this context will not work and an if-else statement is required.

Don't attempt to use a switch statement or nested if/else statements. This is an indication of poor design.

> Is there a more efficient way to do this without having repetitive code?

If you want to share the same `ActionListener` for all your buttons then you would need to write a generic `ActionListener`.

Something like:

```
ActionListener al = new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        cardLayout.show(cards, command)
    }
}
```

Then when you create your buttons you would use:

```
JButton loginButton = new JButton("Login");
loginButton.setActionCommand(LOGIN_PANEL);
loginButton.addActionListener( al );
```

Or you can use a Java lambda to easily create a unique `ActionListener` for each button. Something like:

```
loginButton.addActionListener((e) -> cardLayout.show(cards, LOGIN_PANEL));
```

> I've heard I could use Abstract Action to give multiple buttons the same action

You would use an `Action`, to give provide unique functionality. The benefit of an `Action` is that it can be shared by different components, like  `JButton` or a `JMenuItem`, to perform the same Action.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for the benefits of using an Action over an ActionListener.